# How to fix the clock from flickering?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am currently making an analog clock in java using AWT Package and Swing.  But the digital clock overlay is currently flickering every once in a while and I'd like to fix that.

I've read about implementing double buffered in conjunction with repaint() but I am stuck on how to implement it.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Clock2d extends Applet {

    GregorianCalendar cal;
    Timer clockTimer = new Timer();
    TimeZone clockTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

    public Clock2d() {
        clockTimer.schedule(new TickTimerTask(), 0, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(40, 40, 220, 220);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(50, 50, 200, 200);

        double second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        double minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        double hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            int length = 90;
            double rad = (i * 6) * (Math.PI) / 180;
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                length = 82;
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
            int x = 150 + (int) (95 * Math.cos(rad - (Math.PI / 2)));
            int y = 150 + (int) (95 * Math.sin(rad - (Math.PI / 2)));
            int x1 = 150 + (int) (length * Math.cos(rad - (Math.PI / 2)));
            int y1 = 150 + (int) (length * Math.sin(rad - (Math.PI / 2)));
            g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
        }

        drawHands(g, second, minute, hours);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        g.drawString(sdf.format(cal.getTime()), 120, 20);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));

    }

    public void drawHands(Graphics g, double second, double minute, double hours) {
        double rSecond = (second * 6) * (Math.PI) / 180;
        double rMinute = ((minute + (second / 60)) * 6) * (Math.PI) / 180;
        double rHours = ((hours + (minute / 60)) * 30) * (Math.PI) / 180;
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(150, 150, 150 + (int) (100 * Math.cos(rSecond - (Math.PI / 2))), 150 + (int) (100 * Math.sin(rSecond - (Math.PI / 2))));
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(150, 150, 150 + (int) (70 * Math.cos(rMinute - (Math.PI / 2))), 150 + (int) (70 * Math.sin((rMinute - (Math.PI / 2)))));
        g.drawLine(150, 150, 150 + (int) (50 * Math.cos(rHours - (Math.PI / 2))), 150 + (int) (50 * Math.sin(rHours - (Math.PI / 2))));
    }

    class TickTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            cal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance(clockTimeZone);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Clock 2D");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(330, 330));
        Clock2d clock2d = new Clock2d();
        clock2d.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 320));
        clock2d.init();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(clock2d, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The code work exactly as intended aside from the occasional flickering of the Numbered Digital clock.

Comment: The usual way to implement a clock is by using XOR mode, then every second you redraw the previous time, which erases it, then draw the new time. No clearing required.

Comment: may i ask how different is XOR mode from Double Buffering?

Comment: The difference is that they are not the same. The question is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `public class Clock2d extends Applet` A `java.awt.Applet` is not only deprecated, but also not double buffered by default. Change that to extend a `JPanel` (which is).
2. Then change `public void paint(Graphics g) {` to `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g);` to respect the paint chain.
3. `class TickTimerTask extends TimerTask` use a `javax.swing.Timer` instead. It runs on the Event Dispatch Thread, and any calls to the GUI should be made on the EDT.

Here are those three points, expressed in the code. Do you see the 'flickering' artifacts in this version?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Clock2d extends JPanel {

    TimeZone clockTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    GregorianCalendar cal = 
            (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance(clockTimeZone);
    ActionListener repaintListener = (ActionEvent e) -> {
        cal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance(clockTimeZone);
        repaint();
    };
    Timer clockTimer = new Timer(100, repaintListener);

    public Clock2d() {
        clockTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(40, 40, 220, 220);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(50, 50, 200, 200);

        double second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        double minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        double hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            int length = 90;
            double rad = (i * 6) * (Math.PI) / 180;
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                length = 82;
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
            int x = 150 + (int) (95 * Math.cos(rad - (Math.PI / 2)));
            int y = 150 + (int) (95 * Math.sin(rad - (Math.PI / 2)));
            int x1 = 150 + (int) (length * Math.cos(rad - (Math.PI / 2)));
            int y1 = 150 + (int) (length * Math.sin(rad - (Math.PI / 2)));
            g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
        }

        drawHands(g, second, minute, hours);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        g.drawString(sdf.format(cal.getTime()), 120, 20);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));

    }

    public void drawHands(Graphics g, double second, double minute, double hours) {
        double rSecond = (second * 6) * (Math.PI) / 180;
        double rMinute = ((minute + (second / 60)) * 6) * (Math.PI) / 180;
        double rHours = ((hours + (minute / 60)) * 30) * (Math.PI) / 180;
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(150, 150, 150 + (int) (100 * Math.cos(rSecond - (Math.PI / 2))), 150 + (int) (100 * Math.sin(rSecond - (Math.PI / 2))));
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(150, 150, 150 + (int) (70 * Math.cos(rMinute - (Math.PI / 2))), 150 + (int) (70 * Math.sin((rMinute - (Math.PI / 2)))));
        g.drawLine(150, 150, 150 + (int) (50 * Math.cos(rHours - (Math.PI / 2))), 150 + (int) (50 * Math.sin(rHours - (Math.PI / 2))));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Swing / AWT GUIs should be created & changed on the EDT ..
        Runnable r = () -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Clock 2D");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(330, 330));
            Clock2d clock2d = new Clock2d();
            clock2d.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 320));
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.getContentPane().add(clock2d, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        };
        // .. this is how we ensure that Runnable is on the EDT.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

---

Further tip re fonts:

```
g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
```

Given the paint method is called repeatedly, it would be best to establish the fonts (both of them) when the class is constructed and store them a attributes of the class (which can be referenced in the methods).

But better to use logical fonts instead of something like 'Arial', like this:

```
g.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 10));
```

Not only does that provide compile time checking, but it adapts across OS platforms. For example, the `SANS_SERIF` font would result in Arial on Windows and probably most *nix boxes, but on OS X the default `SANS_SERIF` (undecorated) font is Helvetica.

The other font, Tahoma, is more problematic. Again it's likely to be present on many Windows boxes, but it might be best to either test for it and have a list of backups, or supply the font with the clock app. (assuming you have distribution rights).

Comment: it does, thank you i've been looking for this the entire day

Comment: @BảoTrung if this answer solved your question be sure to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)